# Align is capped in lines? (Using LaTeX in Anki)

Tags: latex, anki

So, I've been trying to create a flashcard of a (rather simple) mathematical proof I did on my own. Now I want to align the equals signs, and it seems to work up to 11 terms, but not more. This doesn't make any sense in my opinion and my mistake is probably somewhere else.

Here is the "code":

```
[latex\]\begin{align} \sigma \left(X\right) &= \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(k - µ\right)^2 \cdot P\left(X=k\right)} \\ 
&= \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(k^2 - 2kµ + µ^2\right) \cdot P\left(X=k\right)} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(k^2 \cdot P\left(X=k\right) - 2kµ \cdot P\left(X=k\right) + µ^2\cdot P\left(X=k\right)\right)} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \cdot P\left(X=k\right) + \sum_{k=0}^n - 2kµ \cdot P\left(X=k\right) + \sum_{k=0}^n µ^2\cdot P\left(X=k\right)} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \cdot P\left(X=k\right) + - 2µ \cdot \sum_{k=0}^n k \cdot P\left(X=k\right) + µ^2\cdot \sum_{k=0}^n  P\left(X=k\right)} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left( k^2 \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) - 2n^2 p^2 + n^2 p^2} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left( k^2 \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) - n^2 p^2} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\left(k-1+1\right) \cdot \frac{n!}{\left(k-1\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) - n^2 p^2} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\left(\frac{n!}{\left(k-2\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} + \frac{n!}{\left(k-1\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} \right) \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{n!}{\left(k-2\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) + \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{n!}{\left(k-1\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{n!}{\left(k-2\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) + np - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(n\cdot\left(n-1\right)\cdot\frac{(n-2)!}{\left(k-2\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} \cdot p^2 \cdot p^{k-2} \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{(n-2)-(k-2)} \right) + np - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{n\cdot\left(n-1\right)\cdot p^2 \cdot \sum_{k=2}^n \left( \binom{n-2}{k-2} \cdot p^{k-2} \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{(n-2)-(k-2)} \right) + np - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{n\cdot\left(n-1\right)\cdot p^2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \left( \binom{n-2}{k} \cdot p^{k} \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{(n-2)-k} \right) + np - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{n\cdot\left(n-1\right)\cdot p^2 \cdot \left(p + 1-p\right)^{n-2} + np - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{n\cdot\left(n-1\right)\cdot p^2 + np - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{\left(n^2 - n\right)\cdot p^2 + np - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{n^2 p^2 - n p^2 + np - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{- n p^2 + np} \\
&=\sqrt{n\cdot p\cdot\left(1-p\right)}\end{align} \[/latex]
[latex] q.e.d. [/latex]
```

Here is the same code without \left and \right to make it more readable:

```
[latex\]\begin{align} \sigma (X) &= \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n (k - µ)^2 \cdot P(X=k)} \\ 
    &= \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n (k^2 - 2kµ + µ^2) \cdot P(X=k)} \\ 
    &=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n (k^2 \cdot P(X=k) - 2kµ \cdot P(X=k) + µ^2\cdot P(X=k))} \\ 
    &=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \cdot P(X=k) + \sum_{k=0}^n - 2kµ \cdot P(X=k) + \sum_{k=0}^n µ^2\cdot P(X=k)} \\ 
    &=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \cdot P(X=k) + - 2µ \cdot \sum_{k=0}^n k \cdot P(X=k) + µ^2\cdot \sum_{k=0}^n  P(X=k)} \\ 
    &=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n ( k^2 \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) - 2n^2 p^2 + n^2 p^2} \\ 
    &=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n ( k^2 \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) - n^2 p^2} \\ 
    &=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n ((k-1+1) \cdot \frac{n!}{(k-1)! \cdot (n-k)!} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) - n^2 p^2} \\ 
    &=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n ((\frac{n!}{(k-2)! \cdot (n-k)!} + \frac{n!}{(k-1)! \cdot (n-k)!} ) \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) - n^2 p^2} \\
    &=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{n!}{(k-2)! \cdot (n-k)!} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) + \sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{n!}{(k-1)! \cdot (n-k)!} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) - n^2 p^2} \\
    &=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{n!}{(k-2)! \cdot (n-k)!} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) + np - n^2 p^2} \\
    &=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n (n\cdot(n-1)\cdot\frac{(n-2)!}{(k-2)! \cdot (n-k)!} \cdot p^2 \cdot p^{k-2} \cdot (1-p)^{(n-2)-(k-2)} ) + np - n^2 p^2} \\
    &=\sqrt{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot p^2 \cdot \sum_{k=2}^n ( \binom{n-2}{k-2} \cdot p^{k-2} \cdot (1-p)^{(n-2)-(k-2)} ) + np - n^2 p^2} \\
    &=\sqrt{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot p^2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} ( \binom{n-2}{k} \cdot p^{k} \cdot (1-p)^{(n-2)-k} ) + np - n^2 p^2} \\
    &=\sqrt{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot p^2 \cdot (p + 1-p)^{n-2} + np - n^2 p^2} \\
    &=\sqrt{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot p^2 + np - n^2 p^2} \\
    &=\sqrt{(n^2 - n)\cdot p^2 + np - n^2 p^2} \\
    &=\sqrt{n^2 p^2 - n p^2 + np - n^2 p^2} \\
    &=\sqrt{- n p^2 + np} \\
    &=\sqrt{n\cdot p\cdot(1-p)}\end{align} \[/latex]
    [latex] q.e.d. [/latex]
```

I don't know why ctrl + k (in StackOverflow) formats it in different ways, but if always used it this way in my code: [latex][/latex]

However, it shows just a blank line and under it "q.e.d." (code with \right and \left):

[image: Incorrect Output]

However, if I just write the first 11 lines, it works:

```
[latex\]\begin{align} \sigma \left(X\right) &= \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(k - µ\right)^2 \cdot P\left(X=k\right)} \\ 
&= \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(k^2 - 2kµ + µ^2\right) \cdot P\left(X=k\right)} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(k^2 \cdot P\left(X=k\right) - 2kµ \cdot P\left(X=k\right) + µ^2\cdot P\left(X=k\right)\right)} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \cdot P\left(X=k\right) + \sum_{k=0}^n - 2kµ \cdot P\left(X=k\right) + \sum_{k=0}^n µ^2\cdot P\left(X=k\right)} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \cdot P\left(X=k\right) + - 2µ \cdot \sum_{k=0}^n k \cdot P\left(X=k\right) + µ^2\cdot \sum_{k=0}^n  P\left(X=k\right)} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left( k^2 \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) - 2n^2 p^2 + n^2 p^2} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left( k^2 \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) - n^2 p^2} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\left(k-1+1\right) \cdot \frac{n!}{\left(k-1\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) - n^2 p^2} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\left(\frac{n!}{\left(k-2\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} + \frac{n!}{\left(k-1\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} \right) \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{n!}{\left(k-2\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) + \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{n!}{\left(k-1\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{n!}{\left(k-2\right)! \cdot \left(n-k\right)!} \cdot p^k \cdot \left(1-p\right)^{n-k} \right) + np - n^2 p^2} \end{align} \[/latex]
```

Here is the same code without \left and \right to make it more readable:

```
[latex\]\begin{align} \sigma (X) &= \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n (k - µ)^2 \cdot P(X=k)} \\ 
&= \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n (k^2 - 2kµ + µ^2) \cdot P(X=k)} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n (k^2 \cdot P(X=k) - 2kµ \cdot P(X=k) + µ^2\cdot P(X=k))} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \cdot P(X=k) + \sum_{k=0}^n - 2kµ \cdot P(X=k) + \sum_{k=0}^n µ^2\cdot P(X=k)} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \cdot P(X=k) + - 2µ \cdot \sum_{k=0}^n k \cdot P(X=k) + µ^2\cdot \sum_{k=0}^n  P(X=k)} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n ( k^2 \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) - 2n^2 p^2 + n^2 p^2} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n ( k^2 \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) - n^2 p^2} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n ((k-1+1) \cdot \frac{n!}{(k-1)! \cdot (n-k)!} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) - n^2 p^2} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n ((\frac{n!}{(k-2)! \cdot (n-k)!} + \frac{n!}{(k-1)! \cdot (n-k)!} ) \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{n!}{(k-2)! \cdot (n-k)!} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) + \sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{n!}{(k-1)! \cdot (n-k)!} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) - n^2 p^2} \\
&=\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{n!}{(k-2)! \cdot (n-k)!} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} ) + np - n^2 p^2} \end{align} \[/latex]
```

This is the output (code with \right and \left, without I just seems to work with 10 lines instead of 11):

[image: Correct output - 1]

[image: Correct output - 2]

[image: Correct output - 3]

I hope you can help me. However, I am a beginner in LaTeX, so I need a rather detailed explanation.

Comment: Please post the pictures, even if they don't render. Someone will edit them to be shown, it's just a spam-prevention mechanism. Regarding your question: I don't know Anki, but it feels like you're asking two questions. If that is indeed the case, please edit this question to be just one question and ask a second one. I wish you a good time on SO :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I removed the second question and added pictures. I wanted to do it beforehand, but somehow it thought the picture were code, and so they had to be formatted as code. To solve that problem, I added "!" in front of the [...][1]s, but this didn't work because I didn't have the permission to render pictures. Now I put empty lines between the pictures and it seems to work.

Comment: @Grey Please don't undo the inlined images - again

Comment: Sorry, did I remove them? I can't remember removing them after it worked properly or what do you mean? But thanks for showing the pictures.

Comment: I already showed them in revision 8 https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72721671/revisions -- just wanted to avoid doing it a third time

Comment: ah, ok, I saw it, thank you.

Comment: Is there a missing image? Because I don't see anything under *Which shows*. Besides that, your `[latex]` tags seem ill-formed. The first one contains a backslash `[latex\]`, and the second one is preceded by a backslash `\[/latex]`. Finally, you don't really need to add `\eft` and `\right` to parenthesis if what's rendered between has a regular size. I say this because the whole thing is a bit unreadable, so removing useless stuff may help.

Comment: Hi, there is no missing image, I removed the line, it belonged to the image above. 
Concerning the formatting of the [latex]: As I wrote, I only used [latex] to start LaTeX and [/latex] to stop it (This is what you get if you press ctrl + t and t successive). The ctrl + k command here in StackOverflow changed it that way.
I removed all \left and \right in the code and added the shortened code underneath, although it then just prints 10 terms instead of 11 (idk why).

Comment: @GreyEminence It's strange because I just copied the code you gave into a new note, corrected the two `[latex]` `[/latex]` issues due to SO's <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> and it Just Works. Maybe you have some add-ons that interfere? You can try starting Anki while holding shift, which should disable all add-ons to see if that helps. Also, be sure to make Anki regenerate the image.

Comment: Besides that, Anki has better support for MathJax than for LaTeX, so maybe that will help (or at least there would be a clear error message). Just replace the `[latex]` with `\(` and `[/latex]` with `\)` to see if that helps.

Comment: I started Anki with holding shift and tried it again, however it didn't work.
Then I replaced [latex] with \( and [\latex] with \) which worked, however I am not a big fan of the styling of MathJax. I would like it to work with normal LaTeX as well but I am glad that it at least works with MathJax.

Comment: As for the equations, MathJax should produce the same results that LaTeX. However, a `\(...\)` block is equivalent to `[latex]$...$[/latex]` (which also has a shortcut, `[$]...[/$]`), which means you can't get LaTeX rendering of regular text with MathJax.

Comment: For me MathJax and LaTeX do not produce the same output. It might be the same font but the MathJax the characters are much more bold and smaller which doesn't look nice in my opinion.

Comment: @BlackBeans What do you mean by "Also, be sure to make Anki regenerate the image." (your third last comment).